# UITableView Parallax Header flickers when reloadRowsAtIndexPath on iOS +11.0

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have `tableView: UITableView` object with a parallax header. Initially, the header height is 3/4 of the screen height.

If the `tableView` is scrolled to a little bit to top and tried to `reloadRowsAtIndexPath`, you will clearly notice a flickering happens.

The flickering occurs only on iOS +11.0 devices. However, if you assigned an arbitrary value to `estimatedRowHeight` that is too high, the `tableView` won't flicker, and vice-versa.

Since the `UITableView` had a lot of changes in iOS 11.0, I might be missing something.

I have initialized a [repo with a sample project](https://github.com/MEnnabah/ParallaxTableViewHeader) for the issue, you can test on iOS +9.0.

Example GIF:
[image]

Note: I have tried too many approaches for the parallax header, the issue always happens.